# Две колонки div: как сделать адаптированные колонки?

Tags: html, css

Ребята, помогите,
нужно чтобы колонки размещались по вертикали, когда ширины браузера меньше двух div-ов 
(вот так https://yadi.sk/i/ew26f1fE3FPpAf )

```
/
```

Пс. при маленьком расширении 2 и 4 колонки не видно
https://jsfiddle.net/dokxpi/krvL01xm/

Comment: Правило @media не пробовали прописывать?

Comment: А что не так с абзацами? Почитайте про адаптивную верстку побольше, все не так сложно. https://habrahabr.ru/post/125247/

Comment: Добавьте в ваш вопрос код, это нужно, на случай если он будет удален с jsfiddle. Полагаю, что и картинку лучше вставить в вопрос. В дальнейшем, данный вопрос может помочь разобраться другим людям, но он не принесет пользы, без кода и картинки(того что требуется получить). Пока вам минус за вопрос поставлю, как только отредактируете, уберу минус.

Comment: Можете колонкам прописать ширину в процентах, вот простой пример Советую изучить bootsrap https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nqykLova/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@media(max-width:480px) {
  .gridbad {
    width: 90%;
  }
}
```

Comment: добавь ширину в класс .gridbad

Comment: Отступ в четыре пробела → блок кода.